# Zend Framework, Doctrine, Entities Setting Configuration on Module (Level) Configuration?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, array-merge, zend-framework3, zend-config

Reference:
Heading "Entities Settings" on the link below
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule#entities-settings

tells to register configurations on module (merged) configuration. However in order to use doctrine from more than one modules, if i use same configuration keys like ;

```
'paths' => [
    'path/to/my/entities',
    'another/path',
],

'orm_default' => [
    'drivers' => [
     // ...
```

will not the other module overwrite the array as values of keys? (yielding the effect as only last module configured to use ORM / Entities).

If the answer is yes then should not we define the configuration in autoload/global.php ?

Answer (score 0):

No, configuration of all modules in ZF is “losslessly” merged, not overwritten by the last one.

For example, if you put the following in `TheFirstModule`’s config:

```
'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity/']
```

and the following in `TheSecondModule`’s config:

```
'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity/']
```

the merged configuration will look like this:

```
'paths' => [
    '…/module/TheFirstModule/src/Entity/',
    '…/module/TheSecondModule/src/Entity/'
]
```